# How do I keep the audio playing over an HDMI cable while the connected display is off in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi

I have the following signal chain over HDMI:  PC -> Onkyo TX-SR608 -> TV.  When I turn the TV off, the audio signal gets killed as well.  Assuming this is a Windows issue...

How do I tell Windows to keep sending audio over HDMI when the video display on the other end is off?

Comment: Actually, this is not a Windows issue.  This is part of the HDMI v1.3+ specifications.  In short, HDMI is trying to be smart in thinking that if you turned off the TV, that you must not want to get the audio stream as well.  Sometimes intelligent design is less than intelligent.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and found a solution that works for my ATI 4850 graphics card.

In Catalyst Control Center I've checked the "Force TV detect" checkbox. Now if I turn off the TV sound goes off for a few seconds, and then comes back again. It isn't ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it couse my TV is only display in my system, but you can try this:

- turn the TV off
- detect displays in CCC (hope HDMI audio will see AVR)
- check sound out